# How to configure the OAuth callback to a different domain in ASP.NET Core authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I am Authenticating against an OAuth endpoint where I can only configure 1 callback domain. (and localhost is whitelisted).

I have my web app running in Azure (myapp.azurewebsites.net) and have it available with two custom domains (myapp.cc and myapp.eu).  When I use the default setup, the CallbackPath can only be a relative path (to the current domain)

The code documentation of `CallbackPath` indicates it's relative to the application's base path:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// The request path within the application's base path where the user-agent will be returned.
/// The middleware will process this request when it arrives.
/// </summary>
public PathString CallbackPath { get; set; }
```

I want to make sure the CallBack happens to the (only) domain that I whitelisted on the OAuth backend.  I know I can implement everything manually, but I was hoping there would be an easy way to work around this design and still benefit from the baked in Authentication options.

So even if a user is logging on on the myapp.cc or the myapp.eu or the myapp.azurewebsites.net , it should redirect to myapp.azurewebsites.net/ (which is whitelisted on my Auth service)

A part of my `Startup.cs` file is pasted below:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyService";
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOAuth("MyService", "MyService",
        options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = settings.ClientId;
            options.ClientSecret = settings.ClientOauthSecret;
            options.CallbackPath = "/relativeonlypath"; 

            options.SaveTokens = true; 

            options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;

            /// ...  removed for brevity
        }
    );
```

Any idea on how to implement this?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's possible, because to verify that the user is redirected to your application as part of a "genuine" authentication flow, the ASP.NET OAuth handler performs the following steps:

1. Before redirecting the user to the OAuth service, ASP.NET Core generates a "correlation" cookie that is tied to the current domain; and
2. When the user is redirected to the app, the handler looks for this cookie and validates its content.

So if the correlation cookie is generated in step #1 for one domain, let's say `myapp.cc`, and the user is redirected to another domain, `myapp.azurewebsites.net`, ASP.NET Core might not be able to read it because the browser will not have included it in the redirection request.

> **Note**
>
> As seen in the first comments, the original thought was to leverage the `SameSite`property of the correlation cookie to have it sent by the browser to the second domain.
> This was all wrong, apologies!

I now think that you have 2 different options:

1. Redirect **every** request from `myapp.cc` and `myapp.eu` to `myapp.azurewebsites.net`, so that when the authentication flow happens, we're already on the right domain; or
2. Redirect the user to the `myapp.azurewebsites.net` domain before redirecting them to the OAuth server.

I won't go into the first solution, as there's plenty of ways to achieve this.

Here's some code that I haven't tested that could work for the second solution:

```
services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "MyService";
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOAuth("MyService", options =>
    {
        options.Events.OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = context =>
        {
            var currentRequestUri = new Uri(context.Request.GetDisplayUrl());

            // 1. If we're not on the correct domain, redirect the user to the same page, but on the expected domain.
            // The assumption is that the authentication flow will also kick in on the other domain (see 2).
            if (currentRequestUri.Host != "myapp.azurewebsites.net")
            {
                var applicationRedirectUri = new UriBuilder(currentRequestUri)
                {
                    Host = "myapp.azurewebsites.net"
                }.Uri.ToString();

                context.Response.Redirect(applicationRedirectUri);
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }

            // 2. If we reach here, it means we're on the right domain, so we can redirect to the OAuth server.
            context.Response.Redirect(context.RedirectUri);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        };
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, Mickaël.  I like your approach and have tried it, but I guess there's something wrong with the Cookie settings (or so), as I get an error : "An error was encountered while handling the remote login": 'Correlation Failed' error when performing the logic.  This happens after the succesful authentication against my OAuth Service, but when I arrive on that new page (in a new domain), that error pops up.  Probably because the cookie/session does not realize they should be the same.

Comment: I thought about it again and the SameSite setting doesn't make any difference here. The browser will not send a cookie created for domain A when you access domain B. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite.

Comment: I think the only approach that would work is to redirect the user to the azurewebsites.net domain before triggering the OAuth login flow to ensure the correlation cookie is created on the right domain.

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer with another potential solution. Not sure if that could work.